# How to upload a project more than 150 M

Tags: jelastic

How to upload a project more than 150 M on Jelastic?

I have a project size of that is 4G, with resources and code.

Also I cannot upload it using FTP, because my login contains symbol '@' that is not correct for Jelastic form of FTP uploading.

Comment: What type of project is this? Git? Or else where is the FTP login with the @ symbol?

Comment: FTP login with the @ symbol. For instance: login is 'admin@tibodic.com' and password is '1234567'.

Comment: Are you trying to use this with the Deployment Manager? (Entering FTP as URL)

Answer (score 1):

Using FTP in Jelastic not depend of the username. Jelastic provides your user name for FTP, such as **jelastic-ftp**.

More information about FTP support you can find in the Jelastic [docs](http://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support)